# When are two different p-norms of the same vector equal?

Tags: real-analysis

Let $\mathbf{x} \in \mathbb{R}^n$ and $1 \leq a \neq b < \infty$. In general, when do we have $\| \mathbf{x} \|_a = \| \mathbf{x} \|_b$, where $\| . \|_p$ denotes the $p$ or $\ell_p$ norm? I think the answer is "if and only if at least $(n - 1)$ components of $\mathbf{x}$ are zeros." If this is the case, how can I prove this?

Comment: Do you mean $\|\cdot\|_p$ means the $\ell^p$ norm?

Comment: I suggest starting with the case $n=2$, to develop some intuition.

Comment: Since the norms scale the same under scalar multiplication, you can assume $\mathbf{x} = 0$, which is the trivial case, or $\lVert \mathbf{x}\rVert_a = 1 = \lVert \mathbf{x}\rVert_b$.

Comment: Daniel Fischer, the zero vector trivially satisfies the equality. My question is about the general case. Also, $\ell_p$ norm of the zero vector is zero not one.

Comment: Buba, your suggestion does not immediately yield an answer to the problem